# Select the record with the MIN(DATE)

Tags: sql, date, min

So, a very simple query, but I'm not sure if I got it right since I'm making this on paper and don't have a DBMS where I can try it on.
It's an exercise for a college exam.
I have this table:

```
    Serv_req
    =============
PK  Svr_ID
    State
    Req_Date
    Description
```

They are simply asking me to show the data for the oldest Serv_Req that has "Open" as state.

What I wrote so far is:

```
SELECT Svr_ID, State, Description, MIN(Req_Date)
FROM Serv_req
WHERE State LIKE 'Open'
GROUP BY Svr_ID, State, Description
```

Now, will this return ONLY the record with the info for the oldest Svr_req? or will it return a list of ALL "Open" requirements with just the date of the oldest one at the end?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention. Unfortunatelly, course rules don't allow us to use `SELECT TOP`, `LIMIT 1`, or even subqueries to create aux tables in the `FROM` statement.

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

**UPDATE 2**
Ok, so, after seeing the first query I wrote is totally wrong, I'm giving it a second try.
Please tell me if you think this is right:

```
SELECT Svr_id, State, Description
FROM Serv_req
WHERE State LIKE 'Open'
AND Req_Date = (SELECT MIN(S1.Req_date)
                FROM Serv_req S1
                WHERE S1.State LIKE 'Open'
                )
```

I know this is not the clearest/most performing way to do this query, but with the limitation my course imposes, it's the best I could come up with. What do you guys think? Does it seem right?

Comment: Are you positive you need to show which server, it's state, and it's description?

Comment: @gangreen Well, yes, that's what it says on the book :). It might be a little confusing, but this are not actually servers but "Service Requirements". So what it asks me is to show the oldest Service Requirement which state is "Open"

Comment: The reason I asked is because the question, as posed, is non-deterministic. What happens if 2 Open Service Requirements fall on the same exact min date?

Answer (score 4):

Nice to see someone else from ARG :)

Well, basically your query doesn't work. You need to remove your second `SELECT`, but just the keyword, not the fields. As of the question you're asking I think you're not quite getting the `GROUP BY`.

The `GROUP BY` in this case will take all `Svr_ID, State, Description` that are distinct (i.e. that make a unique tuple) and the `MIN(Req_Date)` will take the minimum from the elements that where grouped by for each of the distinct touples.

Now, if Svr_ID is a PK your `GROUP BY` won't actually group anything because the Svr_ID is "distinct" in itself, regardless of the state and description fields. That means that query is the same as this query:

```
SELECT Svr_ID, State, Description, Req_Date
FROM Serv_req
WHERE State LIKE 'Open'
```

Is it a bit more clear?

**Edit:**

Now, you said you didn't have a DBMS where you can try those queries out, so let me introduce you to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). I'd recommend you any DBMS but Oracle because the syntax to create new tables and insert records might be a little bit unfriendly.

Now I'm also adding one answer to your question [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e0d9/1). I'm not pasting the answer so that you take your time and play with it. The tables ready for you to play with are [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e0d9/2), so this should be your starting point to test your queries... but remember, always try to solve them on paper first... you won't be able to test them in the exam :)

Comment: Hey! it's a surprise to me as well :), well, it's a small world after all.
I updated my answer to remove the `SELECT`. I don't even know where that came from! it was a typo

About the `GROUP BY` I understand what you say. Basically, this query will retunr all records.

I will update my answer now with another way of doing it that I think it might work. Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: wow, Wow, WOW! I cannot strss how much I've been looking for something like that! Thanks thanks and thanks!! This is brilliant, at last I will be able to try my queries! :D

I actually jus tried the one I updated in my status and it worked!
Thanks man!

Comment: Welcome! Just one tip: As it is an examen you should try to avoid those subqueries, because they are not very performant. Not sure if you are supposed to mention that in the test, but that might help justifying a solution, if necessary

Comment: well, actually I know those subqueries are a horrible way to solve this, but they actually want to "test that we know sub-queries" and that's why they won't let us use some more simple, performat solutions

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Since you cannot use the `TOP 1` trick or subqueries, you need to come up with a condition that spells out the definition of `MIN` using the elementary "less then" relations.

Think about the problem in terms of comparing each record to all records in the same table. You can do it by building a self-join such that all records that you select from the table that you join with have an *earlier* date. There will be some records for which it is not possible to find a pair with a strictly earlier date; that is the record that you want. Obviously, you need an *outer* join to bring the base record into the results, because the match does not exist. The record that you are looking for will have a unique structure letting you identify it among the records that you do not want to see.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to clarify. I can't `SELECT TOP`, or `LIMIT 1`, or even subqueries in the `FROM` statement :(. Kind of silly if you ask me, but those are the course rules

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this another way, the question asks for the oldest Serv_Req.  Taking that literally, the result is a single record i.e. the oldest open one.  That being the case, the very first attempt ("What I wrote so far is:") without the Group By clause would give the answer.
KISS - Keep it Stupendously Simple